# git push issues: Repository not found

Tags: git, github, git-push

```
$ git push
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://xyz@github.com/xyz-space/vendors-platform.git/' not found
```

I just started working with a team lead in a different location and we decided to use git private account. Git organisation, to be precise and I have been added as a member.
I am trying to work on a remote branch but after checking out the remote branch I cant do "git push" as I keep getting the above error. All my efforts to rectify this issue have proved abortive. I would really appreciate the help thanks in advance.

Note: it uses a 2 factor and I have configured it such that it can accept the token password

Comment: git remote add origin https://xyz@github.com/xyz-space/vendors-platform.git/

Comment: can you access the repository via web browser? Have you excluded firewall-related issues? Please post "All your efforts to rectify this issue", it should help with the diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

The same issue happened to me when I tried to Publish the repo via VS Code Source Control Panel to the GitHub server. The repo was created on the GitHub server, but the code couldn't be pushed. After that, the push couldn't be processed via the terminal with the same message:

```
git push
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' not found
```

I have solved it by removing remotes and reinserting them:

- List remotes: `git remote -v`
- Let's say your remote is named `origin`, then you can remove it with: `git remote remove origin`
- Reinsert the `origin` and repo URL: `git remote add origin git@github.com:{USER_NAME}/{REPO_NAME}.git`
- finally, push it to the server: `git push -u origin main`

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the repository URL is correct
2. Make sure you have permissions to read/write to the repository
3. Make sure you are authenticated in git - it should prompt you to sign in. If it doesn't, you can try deleting any saved credentials in your credential manager and try again.

Comment: I was made a member so that takes care of the permission part. when I do  git push I first get to enter my password . I get the error after entering my password so I am sure its not a password error

Comment: I tried cloning the main repo , checking out the remote branch again but I got the same error after I   did git push and I  entered my password